# How can I execute a JavaScript from a html button click?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I want to execute a JavaScript function when a html button is clicked. I have tried many things already they keep giving me the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: TestJs is not defined onclick" How do I can I do this? And thank you!

```js
function TestJs() {
  alert("the alert")
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Coding site!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="myscripts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="category-info">
    <div class="image">
      <h1>Welcome to coding is fun!</h1>
      <img src="737385.jpg" style="width:100%;height:70%">
      <br><br><br>
      <button type="button" id="jstrigger" onclick="javascript:TestJs();">Click me for alert lol</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Onclick attribute doesn't need "Javascript:". Just call the function `onclick="TestJs();"`

Comment: Side nit: JS functions are written in camelCase

Answer (score 0):

In your myscripts.js file write your TestJs function

```
function TestJs(){
    alert("the alert")
}
```

Comment: This is my bad, I do have a js file with a function that writes to console and it gives me an error with no output.

Answer (score 0):

You should add your function. It cannot find otherwise .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Coding site!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myscripts.js"></script> 
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    TestJs =()=>{
    alert( "Here I am, will you add me as a function?  :) ") 
    }
    </script> 
    
    
</head>
<body>
    <div class="category-info">
        <div class="image">
            <h1>Welcome to coding is fun!</h1>
            <img src="737385.jpg" style="width:100%;height:70%">
            <br><br><br>
            <button type="button" id="jstrigger" onclick="javascript:TestJs();">Click me for alert lol</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `javascript:*` form of url is for *inline* javascript, which executes immediately. so you would include the *body* of your code there

```
<button onclick="javascript:alert('the alert');">
```

However, that form is discouraged. A better way is to do this entirely in javascript by making use of [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener):

```js
const button = document.getElementById('jstrigger');

const TestJs = () => {
  alert('hello!');
};

button.addEventListener('click', TestJs);
```

```html
<button type="button" id="jstrigger">Click me for alert lol</button>
```